# How to increase the size of a loop device?

Tags: 11.04

I have a loop device that came pre-installed on my computer. It is mounted atop a NTFS filesystem in the root folder. I heard it increases the performance of ubuntu.

Now the problem is it doesn't have much space, only 5 GB. Is there a way to increase his size? Or do you think I should delete it? How can I do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Cannot understand. Are you using Ubuntu through WUBI? And no, there is no performance increase, just the opposite.

Comment: No, I'm using ubuntu as a unique system. It came pre-installed this way, with a limited space allocated to the root folder / (the loop device is mounted on / folder) and the whole disk mounted on /host folder, a rather strange instalation.

Comment: Sorry for the confusing way I'm writting, I really am confused with this...It seems that the /host folder contains Livecds images to other Linux OS:Mint, Caixa Mágica and even Android...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the best way was to format the NTFS partition and reinstall ubuntu SO in the complete partition.